# How to add the content of an NSArray at the beginning of a non empty NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am adding the content of an NSArray to a NSMutableArray using this method:

```
[InboxArray addObjectsFromArray:TrackArray];
```

However, I need to add the objects contained in `TrackArray` at the beginning of `InboxArray` without using a temporary array. Is there any specific method in Objective-C I can use for this task? (The number of objects in `TrackArray` may vary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addObjects` always appends. You want `insertObjects:atIndexes:`. There is also a method `insertObject:atIndex:` for inserting a single object. Here is a way to do it.

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@"a",@"b",@"c"]];
    NSArray *InboxArray = @[@"z",@"x",@"y"];
    NSRange arrayRange = NSMakeRange(0, [array count]);
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:arrayRange];
    [array insertObjects: InboxArray atIndexes:indexSet];
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

The `insertObjects:` method needs an index set that represents the indexes of the objects in the new array, so the index set needs to be the same length as the array you are inserting `InboxArray`

The output for the code snippet I supplied is:

```
z,x,y,a,b,c
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this to add the objects of `TrackArray` at the beginning of the array:

```
NSRange arrayRange = NSMakeRange(0, [TrackArray count]);    
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:arrayRange];
[InboxArray insertObjects: TrackArray atIndexes: indexSet];
```